# How to show map of world region with dynalic data in rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, wicked-pdf

I want to show world map with region wise data distribution in my application. what are different options available for this in rails application

Example:

say I have 3 region's A,B and C.

Also there are total 20 users from which

10 users belongs  to region A,

5 belongs to region B

5 belongs to region C.

I want to generate world map with region highlighted based on user.

How to do this in rails 3?

**Note**: - `The map generated using this need to be shown inside PDF document.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like google maps? Gem for working with gmap api [Google-Maps-for-Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails)  There is some screencasts with examples too.

For generate to PDF try html generator: [PDFkit](https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit)